# Is there a simple way to give an application information, without making/hosting a database?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm relatively new to programming and wanted to ask, if i can communicate or send information to an C# application, without having a database.

I currently know nothing about databases.

Maybe with Google Sheets?

Comment: txt file, xml, json...

Comment: Databases aren't going to help you with sending info to/communicating with an application - they're there to store data so it's available reliably at a later date.  To that end, you can use any storage mechanism you like, but I'd think using a database would be easier than Google Sheets, unless you really need world-wide high-availability and scalability (which databases can do of course, but not without a fair bit of work).

Comment: it's very vague, how much information are you talking about?  is it shared, and if so with what, other apps, other computers, via network?  Based on your question as it stands you could use a text file or if it's only a few bytes and depending on it's nature the registry or even smoke signals.

Comment: I'd need it to give variables from, as example, my smartphone or my laptop to my desktop pc. I know how to write into and read from xml files, bt that won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an application can get data from any source that you choose and have suitable access to and can code against. It could be a web-service, it could be a flat file on disk, it could be a custom socket server, it could be a database, it could be a no-sql store; it can be *anything you can imagine*. But *implementing* that: is your job.